# Keeping Scroll Position in React ts

Tags: scroll, react-router-dom, antd, react-tsx

How can I keep the scroll position when navigated to another page and returned back?

I used ScrollRestoration that react-router-dom v6 suggests. But the problem is it keeps the scroll position of the whole page(html) not the specific component.Ex:Let's say we have a table when scrolled header must be sticky so height must be given to table but it won't keep the scroll position when navigated. I would truly appreciate your help!